# Dax - How to get the max value from a column compare with Selected date and row by row

Tags: powerbi, dax

My Dax dont work..

**ERROR**:
*A single value for column 'Datum' in table 'tabell' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.*

**Q:**
How to i get the desired values from my dax to get the latest date?
I want it to return the newst date but if its older then the selected values i want it to return that value. I have done a dax but you see the error above.
I want every row to return the Datum or the selected values depedning on the logic.

Selected values '2022-09-01'

desired value = **MAX('tabell'[Datum],selectedvalue(vwdatum[datum].[date]))**

```
Datum         desired value
2020-09-25    2020-09-25
2020-09-22    2020-09-25
2020-01-02    2020-09-01
```

alternativ

IF('tabell'[Datum]>selectedvalue(vwdatum[datum].[date]),'tabell'[Datum],selectedvalue(vwdatum[datum].[date])

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: @UmutK uppdated.

Comment: I still cannot see your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It is much better to create a calculated column, and use this DAX code to evaluate it on a row_by_row basis:

Just write your selected date value into the variable:

```
Desired Value =
VAR SelectedValue =
    DATE ( 2020, 09, 01 )
RETURN
    IF ( Tabell[Datum] > SelectedValue, MAX ( Tabell[Datum] ), SelectedValue )
```

If we test it, It gives us:

[image: GERDDFGH]

SelectedEnd Code For @Jonas

```
SelectedEnd =
VAR aret =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'vwDimDatum2 Slut'[År],2020 )
VAR manad =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'vwDimDatum2 Slut'[Månad nr], 01 )
VAR datumet =
    DATE ( aret, manad, 01 )
VAR sista =
    EOMONTH ( datumet, 0 )
RETURN
    sista
```

Comment: Get this error again: In the real table there is more then one column (like Name) is this an problem? and do i need to group them if so how?
A single value for column 'Datum' in table 'tabell' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Comment: It means your code doesn't return a Scalar value. It returns more than one column or row values which is called a table. You need to create a column and write my code. You don't need to create a slicer because you have only one value to compare '2022-09-01'.

Comment: If use the date(y,m,d) it works but it wasent so easy. The selected value is from a date table and what i know it returns a build up date(y,m,d) but it get this error: Cannot convert value '' of type Text to type Integer. The error is just when i use the Selectedvalue from an other table.....  SelectedEnd = 
var aret = SELECTEDVALUE('vwDimDatum2 Slut'[År])
var manad = Format(SELECTEDVALUE('vwDimDatum2 Slut'[Månad nr]),"00")
var datumet = DATE(aret,manad,01)
var sista = EOMONTH(datumet,0)
return sista

Comment: @Jonas It returns this error; because You are using format() function which always returns a text as output, not a number. I re-wrote your code at the bottom part of my post above. Please check it.

Comment: We coming forward, but now it say the selected value is 1899 12 31 =O

Comment: Oh Okay. I understand. we assigned manat as zero in case multiple values are selected. If we test in this way: Date will be 1900-00-01; but because month is zero, It will go one day back: 1899-12-31.

Comment: In selected value function, You need to assign right values for the second parameter. I changed it some values. If everything goes as expected, It will show: 2020-01-31

Comment: We coming forward, but now it say the selected value is 1899 12 31 =O... I have one table where i make a messure where it just say like SelectedStart = 
 var aret = SELECTEDVALUE(vwDimDatum2[År]) 
 var manad = SELECTEDVALUE(vwDimDatum2[Månad nr],00)
 return DATE(aret,manad,01).... it become yyyy-MM-DD and time. i make it just show yyyy-MM-DD and i present it in a card and it show the right.
But when i do a column where desiredvalue = selecterdstart it say... 1899-12-31

Comment: I have no relation between the tables... the datA table and the datE

Comment: You need to create a relationship always. Share some data, model screenshots on your post.

Comment: If i replace the month with static 01 it become 1900, and if i replace alo year it gave the year and month i inserted static. How can it show the right year month day in the same tabel but when i try to get the selected inside another tabel from the first tabel it show the wrong date

Comment: yes, expected behavior; but Is this what you want?